# tcolorbox: raster of equal height and a minimum height

Tags: tcolorbox

I would like to make a tcolorbox raster, where every box in a row has the same height (easy). But I would also like to use the `height from` key to set a minimum height for the boxes. But as soon as I do it, I loose the equal height feature. Is there a way to combine both?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\tcbset{enhanced,left=1cm}
\tcbset{marktext/.style={overlay={\node[rotate=90,text=black,anchor=north east] at (frame.north west){#1};}}}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3,raster equal height=rows]
\begin{tcolorbox}[marktext=shorter]
blbllb
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[%height from=3cm to 30cm,
                  marktext=somelonger text]
blbllb\\blblb\\blblb\\blblb
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[marktext=short]
blbllb
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[marktext=x]
blbllb
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

#### Result (with equal heights in the row but too small minimum height):

[image]

#### Result when the `height from` is used (middle box is large enough, but equal height is lost):

[image]

Comment: I still don't understand how they work, but last version (3.90) includes some rasters combining rows and columns and rasters inside raster (pp 265-272) which I think can help you.

Comment: @Ignasi if I have to nest something I probaly won't need some inside raster -- a minipage and some strut will work. But the code would be cleaner if I could simply set the minimum height of the box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `minimum for equal height group`, a lower minimal height can be given to an equal height group. Inside a raster, the name of the current equal height group is generated automatically or can be set by `raster equal height group`.

In my proposed solution, I use `\tcb@ehgid`, the internal name of the current equal height group. The `minimum for equal height group` is called with this name and the width of the side text plus some additional space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\tcbset{enhanced,left=1cm}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{marktext/.style={%
  overlay={\node[rotate=90,text=black,anchor=north east] at (frame.north west){#1};},
  code={\setbox\z@=\color@hbox#1\color@endbox\tcbdimto\myheight{\wd\z@+3mm}},
  minimum for equal height group=\tcb@ehgid:\myheight,
  }}

\makeatother

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3,raster equal height=rows]
\begin{tcolorbox}[marktext=shorter]
blbllb
\end{tcolorbox}
\makeatletter
\begin{tcolorbox}[marktext=somelonger text]
blbllb\\blblb\\blblb\\blblb
\end{tcolorbox}
\makeatother
\begin{tcolorbox}[marktext=short]
blbllb
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[marktext=x]
blbllb
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Note that this tweaked `marktext` will raise an error, if no equal height group is set.

Comment: Perfect. I hadn't realized that tcolorbox will do "the right thing" if one use more than one "minimum for equal height group". And the trick with the internal id is neat.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer For the last package update, I was considering a `minimum for current equal height group` option, which would have been helpful here...

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you want but why not just use a strut of some description

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\tcbset{enhanced,left=1cm}
\tcbset{marktext/.style={overlay={\node[rotate=90,text=black,anchor=north east] at (frame.north west){#1};}}}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3,raster equal height=rows]
\begin{tcolorbox}[marktext=shorter]
blbllb
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[%height from=3cm to 30cm,
                  marktext=somelonger text]
blbllb\\blblb\\blblb\\blblb\\
\rule{0pt}{3cm}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[marktext=short]
blbllb
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[marktext=x]
blbllb
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No this will give to large boxes. The requirement is that the side text (inserted with the overlay) is inside the box. So with short text content I need some space at the bottom.  But if the texbody gets longer, the box should simply fit.